# Wrapping parts of text with XML tags using regular expressions

Tags: .net, xml, regex, tags

We are developing our internal tool to produce documentation for our .NET products.

As a part of its functionality, we need to wrap normal paragraphs with the `<para>` tags.

In this context, “normal paragraphs” means that it is one line of text with, maybe, some inline XML-like tags, but not inside other block tags like `<cell>` or `<description>`.

An example of source file:

```
Description paragraph #1.
Description paragraph #2.
<code>
Method1();
Method2();
</code>
<list type="number">
  <item>
    <description>
      If you need to do something, use the <see cref="P:foo1" /> method.
    </description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <description> The <see cref="P:foo2" /> method does this.
The <see cref="P:foo3" /> method does that.</description>
  </item>
</list>

<section>
<title>Section title</title>
<content>
Section paragraph #1.
Section paragraph #2.
</content>
</section>
```

This should be converted to the following:

```
<para>Description paragraph #1.</para>
<para>Description paragraph #2.</para>
<code>
Method1();
Method2();
</code>
<list type="number">
  <item>
    <description>
      If you need to do something, use the <see cref="P:foo1" /> method.
    </description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <description> The <see cref="P:foo2" /> method does this.
The <see cref="P:foo3" /> method does that.</description>
  </item>
</list>

<section>
<title>Section title</title>
<content>
<para>Section paragraph #1.</para>
<para>Section paragraph #2.</para>
</content>
</section>
```

Formally, the task sounds like this: wrap every single line of text with .. but not only if it is not inside a limited list of other tags. White spaces like CR/LF, tabs, space chars, etc are allowed around every future paragraph in the  tags.

Obviously, regular expressions should be used for that, but we have not managed to build something working for this case. Any ideas or tips?

Comment: why not `Method1();`,`Method2();` within `para`..

Comment: Because the contents of the <code> tag is converted into the result HTML <pre> tag and should be placed "as is".

Comment: Can any of the limited list of outer tags be nested? If so you're out of luck.

Comment: @NicholasW, In the general case - yes. But we can restrict it if there is no solution for the general case. Have any code we can look at if we use this restriction?

Comment: Don't use a regex on its own: Parse the XML, then use XPath (or LINQ to XML) to find text nodes that are not children of you set of "don't change" elements. Then process that text: if it really is just each separate line (ie. newline separated) then a `String.Split` and creation of `<para>` elements will do.

Answer (score 1):

You say "Obviously regular expressions should be used". Many would say you are missing a "not" in that assertion. See [this well known answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

In the case that you are sure that there is no nesting of the outer-level tags, you might be able to split on some horrible regex like:

```
(<list([^<]|<(?!/list))+</list>)|(<code([^<]|<(?!/code))+</code>)|([^\n]+)
```

and replace those matches of the non-tag part. But really, why don't you use one of the many XML parsers and simply substitute the appropriate text nodes?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to extrapolate the full requirements from your example, but if your example is typical, then the following XSLT 2.0 stylesheet would do the job, after wrapping the supplied content in a `<wrapper>` element to make it well-formed:

```
<xsl:template match="/wrapper/*">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/wrapper/text()">
  <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., '\n')">
    <para><xsl:copy-of select="."/></para>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```